# How to copy specific lines from one TRichEdit control to another?

Tags: delphi, stream, trichedit

I'm new with delphi and I'm trying to figure out how to load **specific** lines (and not the complete text) from one richtextbox to another one.

```
procedure TForm1.richedit1change(Sender: TObject);
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    RichEdit1.Lines.SaveToStream(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);

    RichEdit2.Lines.LoadFromStream(ms);
  finally
    ms.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: In order to keep formatting when copying one `TRichEdit` to another, see Zarko Gajic example [`RichEdit Append`](http://delphi.about.com/od/tmemotrichedit/a/richedit-append.htm).

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a stream to transfer text lines from one `TRichEdit` to another. Just use the [`Lines`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TRichEdit.Lines) property.
`Lines` is a [`TStrings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings) type, so use its methods for manipulating the `TRichEdit` text.

```
procedure TForm1.richedit1change(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  RichEdit2.Lines.Clear;
  for i := 0 to Pred(RichEdit1.Lines.Count) do
  begin
    if YourSpecificTestFunction(i) then
      RichEdit2.Lines.Add(RichEdit1.Lines[i]);
  end;
end;
```

---

If you want to preserve the RTF formatting, you can use the technique described by Zarko Gajic, [`Append or Insert RTF from one RichEdit to Another`](http://delphi.about.com/od/tmemotrichedit/a/richedit-append.htm).

Another simple option would be to use the windows clipboard and the TRichEdit.Selection:

```
procedure CopyRichEditSelection(Source,Dest: TRichEdit);
begin
  // Copy Source.Selection to Dest via ClipBoard.
  Dest.Clear;
  if (Source.SelLength > 0) then
  begin
    Source.CopyToClipboard;        
    Dest.PasteFromClipboard;
  end;
end;
```

This will also preserve your formatting, copying the selected parts.

If you want to control the selection without user control, use `TRichEdit.SelStart` to position the caret to the character where the selection starts, and `SelLength` for the selection length. To position the caret on a specific line, use:

```
RichEdit1.SelStart := RichEdit1.Perform(EM_LINEINDEX, Line, 0);
```

---

If you don't want to use windows clipboard for the copy/paste operation, a stream can be used:

```
Uses RichEdit;

function EditStreamOutCallback(dwCookie: DWORD_PTR; pbBuff: PByte; cb: Longint;
  var pcb: LongInt): LongInt; stdcall;
begin
  pcb := cb;
  if cb > 0 then
  begin
    TStream(dwCookie).WriteBuffer(pbBuff^, cb);
    Result := 0;
  end
  else
    Result := 1;
end;

procedure GetRTFSelection(aRichEdit: TRichEdit; intoStream: TStream);
type
  TEditStreamCallBack = function (dwCookie: DWORD_PTR; pbBuff: PByte;
    cb: Longint; var pcb: Longint): Longint; stdcall;

  TEditStream = packed record // <-- Note packed !!
    dwCookie: DWORD_PTR;
    dwError: Longint;
    pfnCallback: TEditStreamCallBack;
  end;

var
  editstream: TEditStream;
begin
  with editstream do
  begin
    dwCookie := DWORD_PTR(intoStream);
    dwError := 0;
    pfnCallback := EditStreamOutCallBack;
  end;
  aRichedit.Perform( EM_STREAMOUT, SF_RTF or SFF_SELECTION, LPARAM(@editstream));
end;

procedure CopyRichEditSelection(Source,Dest: TRichEdit);
var
  aMemStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Dest.Clear;
  if (Source.SelLength > 0) then
  begin
    aMemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      GetRTFSelection(Source, aMemStream);
      aMemStream.Position := 0;
      Dest.Lines.LoadFromStream(aMemStream);
    finally
      aMemStream.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, added a link with a solution for preserving formatting, plus a solution that uses the clipboard to do the same.

Comment: +1 but I cannot admire the version that kills the user's clipboard. Very naughty indeed!  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, added a pure streaming version.

Comment: Nice. But you need `DWORD_PTR` if you want to be 64 bit ready. I'm really picky aren't I?!!  ;-)  Did you by any chance promulgate the RTF streaming bug from the VCL code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, edited the callback declaration. Still no success with X64 in XE5 :-(.

Comment: You mean they've still not fixed the bug in XE5?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I had to add the packed keyword to the TEditStream record declaration to get it working for 64-bit. Should I QC this bug?

Comment: Packing seems odd. What does the Windows header file say?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, In RichEdit.pas: `  EDITSTREAM = record
    dwCookie: DWORD_PTR;
    dwError: Longint;
    pfnCallback: TEditStreamCallBack;
  end;
  TEditStream = EDITSTREAM;
`. Compiling with default QWORD alignment.

Comment: No, you need to look at the Windows header files. I'd make a C project in VS. Include the relevant header and then use offsetof to query the layout. Or just look for #pragma. Have to go to the true source.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, never touched VS. See [`MS EditStream structure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787891(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Yup. That tells you nothing of the layout. Trust me, this is a field I know well. Only conclusive evidence is to be found in the headers.

Comment: I bet there's a #pragma(pack, 4) in richedit.h. And if so then it needs to be QC'd.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, mea culpa. The RichEdit.pas file specified `{$ALIGN 4}`, so using that it works without packed.